# What is the expected value of $X_i/\|X\|^2$ when $X \sim \mathcal{N}(\mu, \sigma^2I)$

Tags: random-variable, expected-value, multivariate-normal-distribution, james-stein-estimator

Let $X$ be an N-dimensional normal random vector with non-zero mean $\mu$ and diagonal covariance matrix $\sigma^2I$. I would like to understand if it is possible to derive the expected value of the random variable $\frac{X_i}{\|X\|^2_2}$; in other words
\begin{equation}
\mathbb{E}\left[ \frac{X_i}{\sum_{j=1}^N X^2_j} \right]
\end{equation}
with $i \in \{1, \dots, N\}$.

I found similar questions on StackExchange but the assumptions are usually that $\mu$ is the zero vector, or that the denominator is the norm $\|X\|_2$ (for which one talks about projected normal distribution) instead of the squared norm.

Here, I am only interested in the expectation, and not the distribution itself. A similar expression appears in, for example, the James Stein estimator, and to compute the bias one would need to compute the expectation in question.

Comment: Please check [General Projected Normal Distribution $\mathcal{PN}_k(\boldsymbol\mu,\mathbf \Sigma) $](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bayesian-analysis/volume-12/issue-1/The-General-Projected-Normal-Distribution-of-Arbitrary-Dimension--Modeling/10.1214/15-BA989.pdf).

Comment: Note that conditional on $X_i$, the expectation does not have [a closed form expression.](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2399452/14893)

Comment: @User1865345: it seems that the projected Normal considers $X/||X||$ rather than $X/||X||^2$

Comment: Ah! Yes, @Xi'an. My bad.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer?

Comment: Please consider accepting the posted answer as correct

Answer (score 0):

In [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4784989/formulas-or-approximations-for-mathbbe-left-fracx-x-right-or-m) question I posted, someone gave an answer to your question. For $X \sim \mathcal N(\mu,\sigma^2 I)$:

$$
\mathbb E\left( \frac{X}{||X||^k}\right) = \frac{\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1-\frac{k}{2}\right)}{(2\sigma^2)^{k/2}\Gamma\left(\frac{n}{2}+1\right)}{}_1F_1\left(\frac{k}{2};\frac{n+2}{2};-\frac{|\mu|^2}{2\sigma^2}\right)\,\mu,\tag{$\ast$}
$$
where ${}_1F_1(a;b;z)$ is Kummer's confluent hypergeometric function.